# npm uninstalls itself on npm update

Tags: node.js, npm

I looked for a similar topic in stackoverflow but could not find one, so here it goes.

I've been looking at MEAN stack documentation at http://learn.mean.io/ and just checking some shell commands.

I tried to update npm via

```
npm update -g npm
```

but this came out to give errors

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/cihankoseoglu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

so i tried

```
sudo npm update -g npm
```

but after this command runs , my zsh shell can't find npm. when i type any npm command it simply returns command not found. I had to reinstall Node. what could be possibly causing this? Is it uninstalling npm or altering its PATH in the background for reasons unbeknowst to me?

Comment: You give `npm` root access? Arbitrary things can happen when you give a program root access :)

Comment: it looks like you don't own your own /usr/local directory. Go recursively `chown` it so that everything in it is yours, and npm just works without sudo (needing sudo for npm is the perfect indicator for having the wrong permissions)

Comment: the problem is i am the admin and i own that directory. when i use `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` ~/.npm` on zsh and try ` npm update -g npm ` even without sudo, npm gets uninstalled

Comment: (using Windows 10) Exactly the same thing happened to me, the npm folder is there in node modules after initial installation. I went to npm install fs and fs was successfully installed in node modules BUT the npm folder in node modules was deleted so I cant do anymore installs. Reinstalled nodejs which requires me to restart windows, and then again after one npm install of anything npm deletes itself from the node-modules folder.

Comment: this is the result from simply installing 'fs':     "added 35 packages, removed 219 packages, and audited 36 packages in 8s" 'npm' is one of those 219 deleted packages! node v16.13.1

Answer (score 2):

This is a tried and proven Node.js install technique, afterwards your npm update
command will run OK

Below are the steps to install Node.js from source (OSX/linux)
You may/should issue all these cmds as yourself NOT root (sudo)

NOTE - this installs Node.js which gives you both node as well as npm,
       they come together per release.

to start fresh remove prior node and npm installs as well as these :

```
sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore
```

download source from :    https://nodejs.org/en/download/

```
cd node-v13.6.0
```

define environment variable NODE_PATH as the dir for subsequent module installs

```
export NODE_PARENT=/some/desired/install/path_goes_here

export NODE_PARENT=/usr/local/bin/nodejs # use this if you want to install as root (sudo)
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v13.6.0  # use this if you want to install modules as yourself

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}

make -j8      #  if you have a quad core use -j8 
make install  #  NOTICE not using sudo so install is owned by normal user
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

verify its installed OK just issue

```
node --version
```

> v13.6.0

when you use syntax :

```
npm install -g some_cool_module
```

the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

Now put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such to persist these environment variable changes

going forward when you want to install some npm package avoid using sudo

Comment: what are the differences of installing from source compared to using the nodeJS bundled installer from the website? are you installing into a different path?

Comment: These directions are simple, transparent and bullet proof.  I see many people with issues of Node.js (node/npm) related to bad installs who follow other directions.  As far as differences, well there are many ways to do things wrong when in essence those other install instructions are attempting to do just the above steps, nothing more.